# How do you know if a weapon is 1 or 2-handed without equipping it?

Tags: dead-island-riptide

I'm playing Sam B and and I both prefer two-handed weapons and am spec'ed into it.

I'm wondering how I can know if a weapon is one-handed or two-handed without equipping it (like when I see it in my inventory -- or more importantly: when I see it in a shop and thinking of buying it).

P.S. I haven't got the chance to test it out repeatedly since I just started, but I've noticed I had two wrenches, one was 1h and the other was 2h, and while their icon for blunt weapon was the same, when you selected it the actual wrench icon was different. Is it possible that's how you distinguish? (remembering what icon means what?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think that you have to just make an assumption based on the apparent size of the weapon.  For example, a hammer is fairly easily wielded in one hand, but a staff, on the other hand, would normally be held in two hands.  There are no indicators in the game informing the player of this.